# Snowflake aggregating table by a column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table that looks like below:

[image]

I want to have all the rows for NEW_COL captured by Name as below.

1. The table needs to be sorted by Code
2. Keep 1st row grouped by 'Name' column , capturing all the values of NEW_COL.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

[image]

I have tried below code but not getting the combined value of NEW_COL, it just gets the {"Code" : "A", "Dept" : "Dept Store"} for row 1 whereas I should get {"Code" : "A", "Dept" : "Dept Store"},                            {"Code" : "B", "Dept" : "All other supplies"},                  {"Code" : "C", "Dept" : "Rest"} for the 1st row

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by Name order by Code) 
as row_number 
from TEST where row_number = 1
```

Here is what I am getting with my code

[image]

Comment: what did you do so far, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Provide information as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

It basically needs aggregation of NEW_COL by name and then only select first rows of the result set.

With condition "The table needs to be sorted by Code"
The result-set/expected output shown in question is not as per 'ordered by code'.

Following approach can be used -

```
with data_cte (Name, Address, Code, Dept, NEW_COL) as
(
select * from values
('XYZ','324 NW','A','Dept Store','{"Code" : "A", "Dept" : "Dept Store"}'),
('XYZ','324 NW','B','All other supplies','{"Code" : "B", "Dept" : "All other supplies"}'),
('XYZ','324 NW','C','Rest','{"Code" : "C", "Dept" : "Rest"}'),
('ABC','45 N Ave','C','Rest','{"Code" : "C", "Dept" : "Rest"}'),
('ABC','45 N Ave','B','All other supplies','{"Code" : "B", "Dept" : "All other supplies"}'),
('ZXC','12 SW st','A','Dept Store','{"Code" : "A", "Dept" : "Dept Store"}')
), agg_nc_cte as
(
select Name,listagg(NEW_COL,',') nc_agg
from data_cte group by name
), other_val_cte as
(
select Name, Address, Code, Dept
from data_cte
qualify row_number() over (partition by name order by code asc)=1
)
select a.name,a.address,a.code,a.dept,b.nc_agg
from other_val_cte a, agg_nc_cte b
where a.name =b.name
order by code;
```

| NAME | ADDRESS | CODE | DEPT | NC_AGG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 324 NW | A | Dept Store | {"Code" : "A", "Dept" : "Dept Store"},{"Code" : "B", "Dept" : "All other supplies"},{"Code" : "C", "Dept" : "Rest"} |
| ZXC | 12 SW st | A | Dept Store | {"Code" : "A", "Dept" : "Dept Store"} |
| ABC | 45 N Ave | B | All other supplies | {"Code" : "C", "Dept" : "Rest"},{"Code" : "B", "Dept" : "All other supplies"} |